# Norm of a linear functional involving a composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $ \lambda : L^3[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the linear functional
$$
\lambda (f) = \int_0^1 f(\sqrt{x})dx
$$
What is the norm of $\lambda$ in $(L^3)^*$?

Usually questions of this type seem to involve a product inside the integral so that the Riesz representation theorem can be used but here I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=y^2$ in order to write
$$
         \lambda(f)=2\int_0^1 f(y)ydy.
$$
Then
$$
           |\lambda(f)| \le 2\|y\|_{L^{3/2}}\|f\|_{L^3} \\
               \|\lambda\| \le 2\|y\|_{L^{3/2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I guess the moral here is to always try to bring yourself back to a situation where Hölder's Inequality is applicable.